# Joining two MySQL tables where the join condition is from one of the tables

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

I had did the below code to show the given answer number from answer table and to show answer value and the right answer value from question bank table. But I need it to do the code of two distinct MySQL query in a single query some thing like this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT t1.*, t2.(t1.clicked_answer)
                        FROM Eg_Net_Solution_test_answer AS t1,                                                 
                             Eg_Net_Solution_test_question_bank AS t2
                        WHERE t1.user_serial = '10' AND 
                              t1.area='Hamdun Pur' AND
                              t1.question_no=t.question_no");
```

Is it possible to do the below code in a similar method like the upper one?
`

```
 <?php
  $given_answer_value="";
  $right_answer_value="";
  $question_no="";
  $given_answer_no="";
  $right_answer_no="";
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from  Eg_Net_Solution_test_answer where user_serial='10' AND  area='Hamdun Pur'" );
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {

            $question_no=$row['question_no'];//question_no is a Column of Eg_Net_Solution_test_answer table 
            $given_answer_no= $row['clicked_answer']; //clicked_answer is a Column of Eg_Net_Solution_test_answer table contains value a,b,c,d
            $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * from  $Eg_Net_Solution_test_question_bank where question_no='$question_no'" );
            while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
              {
                $given_answer_value=$row2[$given_answer];// $given_answer is Column of Eg_Net_Solution_test_question_bank table and contains string value. Like $given_answer=a, and this colun a contains value "Prophet Muhammad RIP"
                $right_answer_value=$row2[right_answer];// right_answer is Column of Eg_Net_Solution_test_question_bank table contains vale a,b,c,d
              }
        echo $row['question_no'];  
        echo "(".$row['answer']."). ".$given_answer_value;  
        echo "(".$row['right_answer']."). ".$right_answer_value;  
        }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are just meant to do a `INNER JOIN` between both the tables on `question_no` column. Something like

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.clicked_answer 
from  Eg_Net_Solution_test_question_bank t1 
join Eg_Net_Solution_test_answer t2 on t1.question_no = t2.question_no
where t2.user_serial = '10' 
and  t2.area = 'Hamdun Pur';
```

Comment: Thanks but one thing is left that I need to show the answer value of a certain question no from question table which serial (a,b,c,d) are in the answer table. Because answer table only contains the answer serial but I have to extract the the value of answer with that number.

Comment: Please see I need this one t2.(t1.clicked_answer)

Comment: Just add that column to select list, check edited answer. Anyways, you almost got it.

Comment: Also clicked_answer is the column of t1 means clicked_answer is from answer table.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman, if the proposed answer helped then consider accepting it.